# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 Error when try to use Resident Identity Provider

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Trying to access to Resident Identity Provider the page appears blank.

https://localhost:9443/carbon/idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit-load-local.jsp?region=region1&item=identity_providers_resident

At the logs I can see this error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-22 14:42:52,171] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() fo
r servlet bridgeservlet threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher}
java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit-local.jsp at line 61

58:     ConfigurationContext configContext = (ConfigurationContext) config.getServletContext()
59:             .getAttribute(CarbonConstants.CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT);
60:     IdentityGovernanceAdminClient client = new IdentityGovernanceAdminClient(cookie, backendServerURL, configContext
);
61:    Map<String, Map<String, List<ConnectorConfig>>> catMap = client.getConnectorList();
62: 
63: %>
64:
```

This is happening with 2.1. It was working well with 2.0.

Someone knows how to workaround this?

Thank you,

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed through wum update for APIM 2.1.0.

As a workaround you can copy the following jars from WSO2 Identity server 5.3.0 (`repository/components/plugins`) and paste them in the `repository/components/dropins` folder:

1. `org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance_1.0.2.jar`
2. `org.wso2.carbon.identity.event_5.7.5.jar`
3. `org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task_1.0.2.jar`

Also copy the `identity-event.properties` file (in `repository/component/identity`) from Identity server 5.3.0 and paste it in the same location of the api manager 2.1.0.

Then restart the server.

Comment: Hi Rajith. I am trying to apply the workaround, but the identity-event.properties appears in others locations than repository/component/identity. I found it at repository/conf/identity and repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.server_5.7.5. I will try with the conf and then update this entry. Thank you. JP

Comment: Hi Rajith. I copied the repository/conf/identity/identity-event.properties and it's working. Thank you. JP